# Как вывести из mysql контент содержащий в себе html при помощи node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

Суть в названии вопроса. Подробнее...
на **node.js** делаю запрос к БД

```
    const express = require('express')
    const router = express.Router()

    const pool = require('../database')

    router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
        const articles = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM k2 WHERE (c_id = 72 OR c_parent = 72) AND i_publ = 1 AND c_parent > 0')
        res.render('about-institution/about-institution', { articles })
    })
```

Через шаблонизатор вывожу полученные данные

```
    {{#each articles}}
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card text-center">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <a href="{{c_alias}}/{{i_alias}}">
                                <h3 class="card-title text-uppercase">
                                    {{i_title}}
                                </h3>
                            </a>
                            <p>{{i_intro}}{{i_full}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
```

### В переменных *i_intro* и *i_full* текст с html. Проблема в том, что html выводит, как обычный текст.

Пробовал до этого выводить с использованием **react**, столкнулся с подобной проблемой, но думал, что это из за **jsx**.
Подскажите как решить данную проблему (можно с/без react'a, но лучше оба варианта)
P.S.: шаблонизатор *handelbars*, с использованием реакта изспользовал для создания проекта *create-react-app*

Comment: Куда Вы выводите текст и как?

Comment: Вывод (без реакта) в файл шаблона *.hbs, как - пример кода выше

Answer (score 0):

В бд стоит хранить данные, а не html и проблем не будет. Всё что находится в квадратных скобках будет выводится как текст для безопасности.

Если же нужно вставить в реакте html, используйте [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html).

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'Первый &middot; Второй'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Comment: Я бы и не стал хранить в БД html, но мне надо из базы Joomla тянуть данные, а там в K2 и в обычном компоненте материалов все с html храниться. Попробую ваш вариант.  В любом случае за ответ спасибо.